# Javascript change content based on server time

Tags: javascript, clock

I'm working on a site for a company who's phone lines are only open certain hours of the day. So I'm trying to write a script that says if it's between the hours of 8 AM and 8 PM Eastern time, then show the phone number, if not, show a button leading to the contact form. I can't figure out how to get the clock so it runs off of the server time, and won't change if a user changes their computer clock.

Comment: Why do this with JavaScript and not a server-side programming stack?

Comment: I'm not determined to do it with Javascript, I just don't know much about PHP and wasn't sure the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about *server time* here, I would assume you have access to the back end language. If this is the case you could do something like this

```
<?php
    $h = date("H");
    if ( $h >= 8 && $h <= 20 ) {
        echo '<a href="1800 555 123" rel="tel">Call us</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="/contact">Contact page</a>';
    }
?>
```

This will display a link to a phone number, during your hours of 8-8, otherwise, it will display a link to your contact page

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client-side executed, you can't get the server time from there. You will have to make a call back to the server to get the time.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.